# Finding the largest interval using Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/05-dynprog.pdf
I was doing these questions for practice where I came across one that stumped me.

> 7.(a) Suppose we are given a set L of n line segments in the plane, where each segment has one endpoint on the line y = 0 and one endpoint
>   on the line y = 1, and all 2n endpoints are distinct. Describe and
>   analyze an algorithm to compute the largest subset of L in which no
>   pair of segments intersects.
>
> (b) Suppose we are given a set L of n line segments in the plane,
>   where the endpoints of each segment lie on the unit circle x 2 + y 2 =
>   1, and all 2n endpoints are distinct. Describe and analyze an
>   algorithm to compute the largest subset of L in which no pair of
>   segments intersects.

I figured out how to do 7a, (the question is a disguised problem to find the largest subset of increasing numbers), in O(n log n) time. Im almost close to giving up on 7b, as I cant figure out a way to do it.

However, is there  a way to convert 7b's premise to something more like 7a's? I feel like that's the right way of approaching the problem, and any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't come up with an O(n*log(n)) algorithm, but here is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) one.

The idea is that we build a directed graph with vertices representing segments from the given set and edges representing the "lies to the right of" relation.

Let L be the list of segments: {(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>), ..., (a<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n</sub>)}, where a<sub>k</sub> and b<sub>k</sub> are k-th segment's endpoints.

Let L' be the list of segments: {(a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>), (b<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>), (b<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>), ..., (a<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n</sub>), (b<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>n</sub>)}.

Let the vertices of the graph have indices from 1 to 2*n, each index k representing the segment L'[k], i.e. (a<sub>k/2</sub>, b<sub>k/2</sub>) if k is odd, and (b<sub>k/2</sub>, a<sub>k/2</sub>) if k is even.

A segment (a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>) is said to lie to the right of a segment (a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>) when the points a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>1</sub> are placed in a clockwise order on the unit circle.

Note that 1) If one segment lies to the right of another, they don't intersect; 2) If two segments from L don't intersect, two of the four corresponding segments from L' necessarily lie one to the right of another; 3) Any set of non-intersecting segments from L is defined by a series of segments of L', each lying to the right of the previous one.

[image: Four non-intersecting segments from L; Eight corresponding segments from L'; Four segments from L' found by the algorithm, ordered from left to right]

Outline of the algorithm:

```
for every k1 from 1 to 2*n:
    for every k2 from 1 to 2*n:
        if (L'[k1].a, L'[k1].b) lies to the right of (L'[k2].a, L'[k2].b):
            add a directed edge (k1, k2) to the graph 
Find the longest path in the graph: (k1, k2, ..., km). 
The answer to the problem is: (k1/2, k2/2, ..., km/2).
```

Comment: You are assuming that all the segments are available in the initial set. This does not seem to be the one of the assumptions of the problem.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: What do you mean by available? If you mean that any two points are connected, I don't assume that.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your solution. I think your assumptions are ok. I just didt understand. Is it possible to clarify it?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: I added "from the given set" to the second paragraph. Is it more clear now?

Comment: (1) what do you mean about "angles of segment's endpoints" - which angle are you talking about? (2) What do you mean about points being placed in a clockwise order? Points or angles? (3) a_i can be equal to aj and b_i can be equal to b_j. The question says that the points are different, not the angles. Sorry if I am realy missing the point.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: (1) You're right, angles are irrelevant here and bring unnecessary confusion; I introduced them because I originally intended to do a binary search on them. (2) All the points are placed on the unit circle, and when you traverse (a1, a2, b1, b2), they must appear in a clockwise order. (3) I meant the angle between ((0, 0), (x, y)) and ((0, 0), (0, 1)), but now I removed the mention of angles. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Thank u! I understood your algorithm, but maybe the definition of half segments are still not very clear. I really liked your condition to avoid intersection. +1. Thank you for sharing with us. Can u suggest a good book to introduce these geonetric ideas?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: I added a more detailed explanation and an image. As for the book, I don't know. I came up with this algorithm after reading a part of the lecture linked in the question.

Comment: @user3290797 Hi, but arent u assuming all lines will be vertical. What if we have a line that mirrors the diameter for example

Comment: @user1879789: No, I don't assume any particular orientation of the lines. The "lies to the right of" relation is defined only by a clockwise order of points. For any pair of non-intersecting directed segments (a1, b1) and (a2, b2), there are four possible configurations of points on the circle (clockwise): (a1, b1, a2, b2), (a1, b1, b2, a2), (a1, a2, b2, b1), (a1, b2, a2, b1). (I fixed a typo in the answer). The idea is to select only those pairs of directed segments that have a configuration (a1, a2, b2, b1) and build a graph from them.

Comment: @user1879789: I updated the image, and also got rid of "half-segments" in the explanation, as now I see that they were confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.

We have *2n* endpoints on the circle. Pick any point and start labeling the points in increasing order starting from 1 in clockwise direction. So, we have points labeled from *1* to *2n*. Thus, any line segment *l* can be represented as *(i,j)* where *i* and *j* are endpoints of *l* and *1≤i<j≤2n*.

Let *L<sub>i,j</sub>* be a subset of *L* such that *l=(a,b) ∈ L<sub>i,j</sub>* if *i ≤ a < b ≤ j*. Also, define *D[i,j]* for *1 ≤ i ≤ j ≤ 2n* as the maximum number of non-intersecting lines in *L<sub>i,j</sub>*. We need to find *D[1,2n]*.

We use dynamic programming here. Initialize *D[i,i]* as *0* and *D[i,i+1]* as *1* if (i,i+1) is a line segment, otherwise set it as *0*. We can build D using the following:

```
if (i,j) is a line segment :
     D[i,j] = D[i+1,j-1]+1
else if (i,k) is a line segment and i<k<j :
     D[i,j] = max(D[i,j] , D[i+1,k-1]+D[k+1,j]+1)
else if (k,j) is a line segment and i<k<j :
     D[i,j] = max(D[i,j] , D[i,k-1]+D[k+1,j-1]+1)
else :
     D[i,j] = max(D[i,j] , D[i+1,j-1])
```

Since D occupies *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* space and we compute each cell of *D* in constant time the time complexity of the algorithm is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Reference:
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~robere/csc373h/files/A2-sol.pdf

Look under the heading **Line Intersections (Redux)**

Comment: Try adding some more information other than just linking to an external resource. That way other people might find your answer useful and it will still be valid after the pdf-file is removed.

Comment: Thanks, I will explain the algorithm after preparing the final draft.

Comment: It's much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Create two lists.  The first list has the ordering created by sweeping counter-clockwise around the circle starting at (1,0).  The first endpoint of a segment you hit is marked.  The second list is ordered the same, but go clockwise around the circle.  In this manner, you now have two lists where the segment endpoints show an ordering for intersection.  For example, if the first point in the first list doesn't have its corresponding endpoint first in the second list, then it will intersect with all of the segments which appear before it in the second list.  (You need to be careful here in that both points for a line can be before the end of your segment.  A simple check eliminates this.)  You can then just run the list.  The total complexity of this approach seems to be O(n log n) for each list creation and O(n) for running the list.